# Generate a Guid on compile time

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, constants, guid

I am trying to generate a constant value that I will be using like following:

```
public class Foo()
{
    public const String ExtensionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The compiler is throwing an error:

`The expression being assigned to 'Foo.ExtensionKey' must be constant`

I know that it is not possible to execute a method (a constructor or a type initializer) at compile time. I am looking for a workaround to get randomly generated Guid assigned to different `ExtensionKey` constants of different classes.

**EDIT:**

The intention is to generate a UNIQUE Guid per type. The Guid value must be the same for all objects instances and whenever the application run. This is the behavior of `Const` and I am looking for a way to respect it.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can choose "Tools" - "Create GUID". Or in Windows PowerShell you can say `[Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()`. That will give you a `Guid`. Then you can make the string representation of that particular `Guid` you `string` constant.

Comment: you should have set this as an answer

Comment: I extended that comment and turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Much of this answer "promoted" from a comment to the question.)

In Visual Studio, you can choose **"Tools" - "Create GUID"**. Or in Windows PowerShell you can say `[Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()`. That will give you a `Guid`. Then you can make the string representation of that particular Guid your `string` constant.

```
public const string ExtensionKey = "2f07b447-f1ba-418b-8065-5571567e63f6";
```

The `Guid` is fixed, of course. A field marked `const` is always `static` (but you must not supply the `static` keyword; it is implied).

If you want to have the field of `Guid` type, then it can't be declared `const` in C#. Then you would do:

```
public static readonly Guid ExtensionKey = new Guid("2f07b447-f1ba-418b-8065-5571567e63f6");
```

`readonly` means that the field can only be changed from a (`static` in this case) constructor of the same class (a constructor of a derived class is not OK).

Answer (score 4):

Call to `Guid.NewGuid()` will return you a new GUID every time, this is why you get an exception. You can replace  `const` with `readonly` or `static` or use a fixed GUID string with `const`.

```
public class Foo
{
    // Fixed "forever" or until you manually change it
    // Cannot be changed in run-time
    public const String ExtensionKey = "3c88c196-06ec-4a89-bffa-6f3fd221f425";

    // You will get a new GUID per each Application Domain and per each run
    // Can be changed
    public static String ExtensionKey1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    // By convention this shall be private, as it's a field
    // You will get a new GUID per each instance of a class,
    // Once assigned, the value cannot be changed
    public readonly String ExtensionKey3 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    // You will get a new GUID per each Application Domain and per each run,
    // Once assigned, the value cannot be changed
    public static readonly String ExtensionKey4 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

---

**Edit**

> The intention is to generate a UNIQUE Guid per type. The Guid value
>   must be the same for all objects instances and whenever the
>   application run.

Generate a new GUID manually and use the first option

```
    // Fixed "forever" or until you manually change it
    // Cannot be changed in run-time
    public const String ExtensionKey = "3c88c196-06ec-4a89-bffa-6f3fd221f425";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get almost the same behavior by replacing `const` with `static readonly`

```
public static readonly String ExtensionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: This will generate a different Guid for each object instance. I need a unique Guid among all instances

Comment: And if it were changed into `static`, this would create a new `Guid` every time the application was run.

Answer (score 1):

This question lacks a bit of details; do you want your GUID to be unique per class and process, or unique per class, but the same every time you start your program? It's two very different things.

If you want a unique GUID per class and process then you have some valid answers already, but if you want a unique GUID per class, but not per process, then you need some other way of solving your problem. Either you enter a GUID in your code, or you use some kind of GUID generator that uses some text as input instead of some random number generator based on the clock or similar.

I would suggest reading this [blog post](http://code.logos.com/blog/2011/04/generating_a_deterministic_guid.html) about generating a GUID from a string, the actual code resides on [GitHub](https://github.com/LogosBible/Logos.Utility/blob/master/src/Logos.Utility/GuidUtility.cs).

By using something like that and using the full name of the class as input you will get a unique GUID per class, but still the same for every process